# Incrementing sequence with string prefix from foreign_key column

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is the `Cluster` table:

```
╭────╥────────────┬─────────────╮
│ id ║  name      │   prefix    │
╞════╬════════════╪═════════════╡
│ 1  ║ Yard work  │ YA          │
│ 2  ║ Construc.. │ CR          │
└────╨────────────┴─────────────┘
```

Both `name` and `prefix` have uniqueness and non-null constraints.

Now we get to a material table where each row has a foreign key to a cluster.

```
╭────╥──────────────┬─────────────╮
│ id ║  cluster_id  │ name        │
╞════╬══════════════╪═════════════│
│ 1  ║ 1            │ Shovel      │
│ 2  ║ 1            │ Lawn mower  │
└────╨──────────────┴─────────────┘
```

We want to give each material another unique identifier (perhaps as the primary key even) which I can't quite figure out how to write the sequence for:

1. Prefix with a hard coded letter (`W` from here on)
2. Take the `prefix` of the cluster (`YA` from here on)
3. Given what we have now (`W-YA`) find the last value and increment by 1, this should end up being 5 characters long and padded with 0

So we would end up with, given that ^ example,

1. W-YA-00001
2. W-YA-00002
3. W-YA-00003

With another cluster_id we would then end up with

1. W-CR-00001
2. W-CR-00002

I imagine this is solved through `CREATE SEQUENCE` but I'm not sure where to start at all.

Note that the clusters table can receive new rows at any given moment. A row can neither change nor be deleted though.

Rows from `cluster_materials` can NOT be deleted, and the cluster_id can *NOT* be changed.

**UPDATE:** Sequences are not the way to go here as I need to guarantee a gapless increase in the numbers, which sequences do not provide.

**UPDATE 2:** [Gapless Sequences for Primary Keys](http://www.varlena.com/GeneralBits/130.php) does describe how to achieve gapless keys, and I think it could be modified to fit my needs. However it does seem like if an insert fails here this would blow up as the count was incremented but the row is never inserted (say because it doesn't pass all constraints.) I guess that can be solved with transactions.

**UPDATE 3:** I'm slowly making progress in this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/791ed/2

**UPDATE 4:** Latest progress. This is working just fine right now. It does not do any locking however and I don't know exactly how it works during concurrent inserts (which aren't an issue but locking would probably be good to prevent any unexpected issues in the future.) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7ad0f/9

Comment: Any implementation of gapless sequence leads to performance deterioration. Does performance (concurrent inserts) important for you?

Comment: @VladimirAleshin concurrent inserts are not an issue at all. Once the table is loaded with initial data the number of inserts will be very few.

Comment: **why** must the keys be gapless? **why** are you constructing "primary keys" like this?

Comment: @wildplasser for reasons that are not my own but necessary. They are _NOT_ primary  keys.

Comment: what (in your example) should happen if `W-YA-00002` is deleted? should `W-YA-00003` be renamed into `W-YA-00002` ?

Comment: @wildplasser good point I never mentioned that. I will add it to the question. A row can never be deleted from, only hidden through a boolean. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

If performance is not an issue at all, then I suggest you following solution:

Schema:

```sql
create table cluster (
  id     bigint primary key,
  name   text   not null unique,
  prefix text   not null unique
);

create table material (
  id         text   primary key,
  cluster_id bigint not null references cluster,
  name       text   not null
);
```

Some data for cluster:

```sql
insert into cluster (id, name, prefix)
values
  (1, 'Yard work', 'YW'),
  (2, 'Construc..', 'CR');
```

Stored procedure that adds materials:

```sql
create or replace function add_material(
  p_cluster_id bigint,
  p_name       text
) returns text as
$body$
  -- for gapless ids
  -- prevents concurrent updates and inserts
  -- release on commit or rollback
  lock table material in exclusive mode;

  insert into material (id, cluster_id, name)
  select
    'W-' || c.prefix
         || '-'
         || lpad(
              (
                select coalesce(max(substring(m.id from '.....$')::integer) + 1, 1)
                from material m
                where m.cluster_id = c.id
              )::text,
              5,
              '0'
            ) id,
    c.id cluster_id,
    p_name as "name"
  from cluster c
  where c.id = p_cluster_id
  returning id;
$body$
  language sql volatile;
```

Example of usage:

```sql
select add_material(1, 'test1');
```

Result: `W-YW-00001`

```sql
select add_material(1, 'test2');
```

Result: `W-YW-00002`

```sql
select add_material(2, 'test3');
```

Result: `W-CR-00001`

To increase performance for `select max(...)` you could add index on `material (cluster_id, substring(m.id from '.....$')::integer)`

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your answer! Unfortunately I didn't specify that a function for adding material won't quite work, or maybe it would, as we're using an ORM (ActiveRecord from Rails in this case) for most db operations.

However you've given me some good inspiration and I thank you for that! The effort is much appreciated and I learned a little bit while reading your code, especially that I hadn't considered locking!

Comment: It is not necessary to use stored procedure like in my example. You could just lock table and then perform insert-select from your application

Comment: While that's theoretically possible it doesn't enforce anyone to do it, and it makes things very awkward for working in Rails. I'm definitely looking for a solution that does this for us automatically without us having to think about it.

Answer (score -1):

- this is a terrible design; you should **not** compose (candidate)keys from (concatenations of) expressions, and **certainly not** from aggregates.
- since your composed identifier is functionally dependent on the actual keys, it can be constructed on the fly (in this case: based on a window-function)
- using some particular ORM is not a reason for a bad database design. Never.

---

```
CREATE TABLE clus (
        id integer not null primary key
        , name varchar UNIQUE
        , prefix varchar(2) UNIQUE
        );

INSERT INTO clus(id, name, prefix)VALUES
(1,'Yard work','YA' ), (2,'Construc..', 'CR' );

-- Both name and prefix have uniqueness and non-null constraints.
-- Now we get to a material table where each row has a foreign key to a cluster.

CREATE TABLE mat (
        id integer not null
        , cluster_id integer not null REFERENCES clus(id)
        , name varchar UNIQUE
        , PRIMARY KEY(id,cluster_id)
        );

INSERT INTO mat(id, cluster_id, name)VALUES
( 1  , 1            , 'Shovel' ) ,( 2  , 1            , 'Lawn mower')
,( 5  , 1            , 'fire hose' );

SELECT omg.*
        , 'W-' || omg.pfx || '-' || to_char(omg.rnk, 'FM0000') AS wtf
        FROM(SELECT c.id AS cid, c.name AS cname, c.prefix AS pfx
                ,m.id AS mid, m.name AS mname
        , rank()over (partition by m.cluster_id ORDER BY m.id) AS rnk
        FROM clus c
        JOIN mat m ON m.cluster_id = c.id
        ) omg
        ;
```

---

Result:

---

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 2
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 3
 cid |   cname   | pfx | mid |   mname    | rnk |    wtf    
-----+-----------+-----+-----+------------+-----+-----------
   1 | Yard work | YA  |   1 | Shovel     |   1 | W-YA-0001
   1 | Yard work | YA  |   2 | Lawn mower |   2 | W-YA-0002
   1 | Yard work | YA  |   5 | fire hose  |   3 | W-YA-0003
(3 rows)
```

Comment: First: By your design the key is not stored in the table, and is subject to change based on the order of selection. 

Second: While I did comment on the other answer from Vladimir that an `add_material` function would be awkward to use in an ORM, you could always argue that it is indeed the right choice. The "design" here is not based on the ORM.

Comment: `...  subject to change based on the order of selection.` No it is not. in the comments you stated that the keys are stable and rows are never deleted.

Comment: What if I, say, ORDER BY cluster_id DESC?

Comment: This is also the XY problem (in disguise) `... By your design the key is not stored in the table,` The key to DB-design and normalisation is not to store redundant data. Your identifiers are functionally dependent on existing data.

Comment: ^ agreed on that part. However, and I guess this should be added to the question then, I will need to sometime query by internal_id. So I'm quite sure this column needs to be part of the table.